# Find combination of vectors from array that sum up to s

Tags: algorithms, arrays

I have an array of $n$ $m$-dimensional vectors (in my case, they're 27 dimensional). I also have an $m$-dimensional vector $s$. I want to find all combinations of $k$ vectors from my array whose vector sum is equal to $s$. How to do this efficiently?

The best I could do is just a brute force which is $O(n^k)$ and impossibly slow.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ if fixed, you cannot do much better than enumerating all subsets of vectors.

$\binom{n}{k} = \Omega\big((\frac{n}{k})^k\big)$ is a lower bound in general. Let all input vectors be equal to $(1,1, \dots,1)$ and let $s=(k, \dots, k)$. 
There are $\binom{n}{k} \ge (\frac{n}{k})^k$ distinct sets of $k$ vectors that satisfy your property.

Answer (score 3):

If $k$ is part of the input, the problem is NP-complete even when $m=1$ (and when we want to know if there's even a single solution). That is, when $m=1$, we essentially have a collection of $n$ values and our task is to decide if there is a subset of those that sum up to a target $s$. This is known as [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

The Wikipedia page lists algorithms that you might be able to adapt to your more general case as well. Also, if $k$ is small enough, you might be able to do something better.

Comment: Considering that the size of a subset is fixed for a given instance of the problem, is this still NP-Complete?

Comment: @JhonRayo99 No, just try all $\Theta(n^k)$ subsets; that's a polynomial time algorithm.